# Hostas in river rock - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

Last year I put water permeable fabric and then river rock down on a slope that sends water runoff toward my garage. A furrow at the edge of the rock helps direct the runoff away slightly better.

It’s a shady spot with only morning sun so I plopped a few gallon hostas in there.

So far this year they’re ok but I’m concerned I’m guessing. Anything I should do to make sure they thrive? Back off the rock around each a bit maybe?

FYI, I have been applying the rabbit repellent.

Please take a look:

[image: hosta in river rock 1]

[image: hostas in river rock]

Thanks for any advice.